# Calling pthread_cond_destroy results in "Function not implemented" ENOSYS on macOS

Tags: macos, pthreads, posix

I am trying to make some Linux-based code run on macOS. It is the POSIX OSAL layer for NASA Core Flight System as found here: https://github.com/nasa/osal.

I am observing that the code uses POSIX conditions and in particular, there is a call like the following:

```
if (pthread_cond_destroy(&(sem->cv)) != 0) {
    printf("pthread_cond_destroy %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno)); // my addition
    ...
}
```

On macOS, the tests related to this code provided in the OSAL repository always fail because the call to `pthread_cond_destroy` always results in:

```
pthread_cond_destroy 78 Function not implemented
```

I have found an example in the Apple documentation which shows an example of [Using Conditions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW4) (Threading Programming Guide / Synchronization / Using Conditions) and in that example there is no call to `pthread_cond_destroy` but I cannot make any conclusions on whether that call should be there or not because the example is simplified.

This is how the header looks like on my machine:

```
__API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.4), ios(2.0))
int pthread_cond_destroy(pthread_cond_t *);
```

I am wondering if `pthread_cond_*` functionality is simply missing on macOS and I have to implement a replacement for it or there is some way to make it work.

EDIT: The minimal example is working fine for me. The problem should be somewhere around the problematic code. What I still don't understand is why I am getting ENOSYS/78 error code, for one thing it is not mentioned on the man page [man/3/pthread_cond_destroy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_destroy):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

int main() {
  pthread_cond_t condition;
  pthread_cond_init(&condition, NULL);
  int result = pthread_cond_destroy(&condition);
  assert(result == 0);
  assert(errno == 0);
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pthread_cond_destroy` is certainly a part of POSIX. Maybe, osal wasn't compiled/installed properly(?). Their doc says to set `OS=posix` in `build/osal-config.mak`. Was that set when compiled on MacOS? Does *static initializer* work e.g., `pthread_cond_t condition = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;` ?

Comment: That was my assumption: pthread_cond_destroy should work. I am trying to bisect the OSAL code to find what makes it different compared to the minimal example and so far everything looks similar. I am fairly certain that I am compiling the right posix code (but I will double-check). I will post my findings when I know more.

Comment: I think I have bisected it and now I think there is a possible bug. https://github.com/nasa/osal/issues/337

Comment: Certainly looks like a bug. I noted the original commit there. Hopefully, someone will fix it.